# Working with Anonymous Types with Linq in VB, C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, types, set

Say I create two sets of tuples like so:

```
    Dim losSPResults As List(Of spGetDataResults) = m_dcDataClasses.spGetData.ToList
    Dim loTupleKeys = From t In losSPResults Select t.key1, t.key2

    '' Query on an existing dataset:
    Dim loTupleExistingKeys = from t in m_losSPResults Select t.key3, t.key4
```

Now I want to perform set operations on these two lists like so:

```
    Dim loTupleSetDifference = loTupleKeys.Except(loTupleExistingKeys)
```

Obviously, Linq can't perform a comparator on sets if it doesn't know the sets have uniform definitions, so it will give me this build error:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit
>   conversions from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of
>   < anonymous type>)' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of
>   < anonymous type>)'.

How do I work with the declaration of these sets to make them mesh? (Not much luck on google)

[Edit]
Still getting the same compile error:

```
    '*** If we have initialized the list of tools, check to make sure it's up to date
    Dim loTupleDatabaseTools = From tt In lottTorqueTools _
                               Select StationIndex = tt.station_index, SlotNumber = tt.slot_number
    Dim loTupleToolObjects = From tt In m_lottTorqueTools _
                             Select StationIndex = tt.StationIndex, SlotNumber = tt.SlotNumber

    Dim loTupleSetDifference = loTupleDatabaseTools.Except(loTupleToolObjects)
```

Error is here:

Dim loTupleSetDifference = loTupleDatabaseTools.Except(**loTupleToolObjects**)

> Error 5   Option Strict On disallows
>   implicit conversions from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of
>   < anonymous type>)' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of
>   < anonymous type>)'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the anonymous types have the same property names with the same types in the same order, they should be the same types (and thus compatible).

EDIT: Based on the comments and the updated question, I suspect the bit you're missing is the ability to name the properties in anonymous types. Change this:

```
Dim loTupleExistingKeys = from t in m_losSPResults Select t.key3, t.key4
```

into this:

```
Dim loTupleExistingKeys = from t in m_losSPResults Select key1=t.key3, key2=t.key4
```

So long as the types are right, you may then be okay with no more work.

Comment: Ah. I made an edit to the names of the columns above. That must be the problem--the names differ? How can I fix that?

Comment: I wish I could, but unfortunately our DBAs chose not to conform column names to the same naming conventions as we use for code. One dataset is composed of a stored procedure result set, the other is a list of objects. Is there an easy way to either change or ignore the names or will I have to copy these into uniformly named data sets?

Comment: Well these are anonymous types, right? You get to choose the names: "Select Key3 = t.Key1" etc

Comment: Are the types of the various properties the same in both anonymous types?

Comment: Ah! They were not. They are now and it compiles. Excellent. Thank you much.